# Observable and xhr.upload.onprogress event

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I have two services.

1) `UploadService` - send file throug ajax to server, and also get and store progress value (inside xhr.upload.onprogress event handler)

2) `SomeOtherService` worked with DOM, get progress value from first service, displayed it on Bootstrap progressbar.

Because, `xhr.upload.onprogress` is asynchronious - i use `Observable` in first service:

```
constructor () {
    this.progress$ = new Observable(observer => {
        this.progressObserver = observer
    }).share();
}

private makeFileRequest (url: string, params: string[], files: File[]): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
            xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                } else {
                    reject(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
            this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

            this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
        };

        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

Insise second service, i subscribe on this observer:

```
this.fileUploadService.progress$.subscribe(progress => {
    this.uploadProgress = progress
});

this.fileUploadService.upload('/api/upload-file', [], this.file);
```

**Now my problem:**

That code does not work. In second service i get observed value only once, on 100%.

But if i insert (yes, with empty callback body)

```
setInterval(() => {
}, 500);
```

inside makeFileRequest method - i will get progress value inside second service every 500 milliseconds.

```
private makeFileRequest (url: string, params: string[], files: File[]): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
            xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                } else {
                    reject(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        };

        setInterval(() => {
        }, 500);

        xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
            this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

            this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
        };

        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

What is that? Why that happened? How i can correct use Observable with `onprogress` event without that setInterval?

UPD: after Thierry Templier answer inside

```
this.service.progress$.subscribe( data => { 
    console.log('progress = '+data); 
});
```

i got correct values, but that values not updated inside template dynamically, only on 100% again.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the complete code so it's difficult to give you a precise answer.

The fact you tell that "In second service i get observed value only once, on 100%." makes me think that it should be related to the use of promises. As a matter of fact, promises can be resolved or rejected once. There is no support of multiple events contrary to observables.

If you can post a plunkr with you code, I'll be able to debug it so I should provide you a more precise answer.

**Edit**

I created a plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/ozZqbxIorjQW15BrDFrg?p=preview) to test your code and it seems that it works. By changing the promise into an observable, I get more progress hints.

```
makeFileRequest(url: string, params: string[], files: File[]): Observable> {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
        xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                observer.complete();
            } else {
                observer.error(xhr.response);
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
        this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

        this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
    };

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.send(formData);
  });
}
```

Here is the traces I had:

```
app.component.ts:18 progress = 21
app.component.ts:18 progress = 44
app.component.ts:18 progress = 71
app.component.ts:18 progress = 100
```

With the promise, I only get two traces

Comment: Thank you, now inside

    `this.service.progress$.subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('progress = '+data);
      });`

i got correct values, but that values not updated inside template.

Comment: important thing - inside template progress values updating again on 100%

Comment: Okay. How do you display the progress values in your component?

Comment: just through `{{ uploadProgress }}`, where uploadProgress - property of second service.

Comment: Thierry, I had the similar problem. Progress bar not updated automatically. I have to click. From the console, progress data are displayed correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046757/ui-is-not-updated-automatically-when-value-is-available-from-the-observable

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as @КачаловТимофей, however, I'm using just Observables, so Promises don't affect this issue at all. Just try to get the values you update with `this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);` on a component with an associated view, and then interpolate the values into the html... surprisingly for me, even if I can print the updated values into console.log()  (like in your plunkr), the interpolated variable doesn't updates the view if I don't use the `setInterval`creepy hack :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the issue by wrapping with `zone.run(() => ...)`. Import `NgZone`, inject it into your constructor, and do something like this:

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
    this.service.progress$.subscribe(progress => {
        this.zone.run(() => this.uploadProgress = progress);
    });
}
```

**The above is what actually works with the angular@2.0rc1. Below is what I think should work, but simply didn't work in my tests.**

The reason you are not seeing updates is because change detection in Angular 2 is performed by reference, and the reference to your observable property is not changing. You can solve this by telling angular that it should run change  detection manually like so:

```
this.service.progress$.subscribe(progress => {
    this.uploadProgress = progress;
    this.cd.markForCheck();
});
```

where `cd` needs to be injected into your constructor like so:

```
 constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

after importing `ChangeDetectorRef` from `@angular/core`.

For more details you can see [this excellent article on Thoughtram](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html). I have reproduced the most relevant tidbits but the whole article is worth reading!

> ... let’s take a look at this component:

```
@Component({
  template: '{{counter}}',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
class CartBadgeCmp {

  @Input() addItemStream:Observable<any>;
  counter = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addItemStream.subscribe(() => {
      this.counter++; // application state changed
    })
  }
}
```

> ... the reference of addItemStream will never change, so change detection is never performed for this component’s subtree. This is a problem because the component subscribes to that stream in its ngOnInit life cycle hook and increments the counter. This is application state change and we want to have this reflected in our view right?
>
> ... what we need is a way to detect changes for the entire path of the tree to the component where the change happened. Angular can’t know which path it is, but we do.
>
> We can access a component’s ChangeDetectorRef via dependency injection, which comes with an API called markForCheck(). This method does exactly what we need! It marks the path from our component until root to be checked for the next change detection run.
>
> Let’s inject it into our component: `constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}` Then, tell Angular to mark the path from this component until root to be checked:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.addItemStream.subscribe(() => {
      this.counter++; // application state changed
      this.cd.markForCheck(); // marks path
    })
  }
```

> Boom, that’s it!