# UI is not updated automatically when value is available from the observable

Tags: angular, pipe

In angular2, I create the observable _uploadProgressStatus, which takes in numbers. Using async pipe, I want to display the number on the UI and updated automatically when a new values is kicked in. Pls refer to the codes below.

home.component.ts is observing the data from upload.service.ts

```
public  _uploadProgressStatus:Observable<number>;

this._uploadProgressStatus = this._uploadService._progress$;
```

home.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="_startUploadFlag" class="container">
  <h4>Uploading...{{_uploadProgressStatus | async | percent}}</h4>
</div>
```

upload.service.ts

```
 uploadVideo(file:File):Promise<Video> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
       authenCode = this._authenservice.authenticate(),
        xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      console.log('getVideos:authenCode is' + authenCode);
      let path = this._configurationService.getAPI('API_VIDEOMANAGEMENT_UPLOAD');
      console.log('upload video to:' + path);
      xhr.open('POST', path, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log('xhr status 200');
            resolve(<Video>JSON.parse(xhr.response));
          } else {
            console.log('xhr status rejected:'+xhr.status);
            reject(xhr.response);
          }
        }
      };
      xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
        this._progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
        console.log('inside of xhr.upload.onprogress:'+ this._progress);
        this._progressObserver.next(this._progress/100);
      };
      formData.append("file", file, file.name);
      xhr.send(formData);
    });
  }
```

The problem I encounter is numbers come in without a problem, but UI is not updated. However, whenever I click on the `<h4>`, the correct values is displayed. Just not automatically updated there. Any idea?

Comment: How is `this._uploadService._progress$` created?

Comment: I update the code. this._uploadService._progress$ get the values from xhr.upload.onprogress

Comment: In the first code block you use `this._uploadService._progress$`. `_progress$` isn't referred to anywhere in the code below. Do you set it at all?

Comment: public _progress$: Observable<number>;
      private _progress: number = 0;
      private _progressObserver: Observer<number>;
      constructor(private _http:Http, private _configurationService: ConfigurationService,private _authenservice:AuthenticationService) {
        this._progress$ = new Observable(observer => {
          this._progressObserver = observer
        });
      }

Comment: I did not paste the initialization code from update. component.ts, where i append in the last comment. Observable part data flow is correct according to the logs

Comment: It might be correct but I have no way in understanding what's going on without seeing the code.